# Home-made Carbonite

Tags: materials

Is there a real-life material resembling Star Wars Carbonite? For practical reasons, define the property profile as such: hard enough to immobilize a person, but permeable to air. (Maybe a BDSM movie producer could use it :-) My first thought was aerogel, but I'm a chemist, not a material scientist, and don't know.

Comment: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Carbonate is a real material but no ficticious properties that could hold Han Solo at bay.

Comment: You can't breathe if you can't expand your chest. And that's if the material is permeable *enough* to air. You  need to be able to exhale carbon dioxide through that too. If it takes too much pressure and the CO2 just builds up too close you also suffocate.

Comment: Pumice, perhaps?